# IdentityServer4 - Understanding flows and Endpoints. How is it related to OAuth and OpenIDConnect?

Tags: reactjs, authentication, asp.net-core, oauth, identityserver4

I am integrating the security aspect of webapplication. I have decided to use OAuth, 
so we have a **REST WebApi** in AspNet Core 3.0, the client which is a **SPA created in React**, and the **Identity Server 4.0** app which is also in AspNet Core 3.0.

I read that OAuth is created for Authorization and not for Authentication.
For Authentication, seems that exists something else called OpenIDConnect, so the first question that comes to my mind, and on which I cannot find an easy answer is: **are OAuth, OpenIDConnect and IdentityServer related technology?**

Which is the best solution for authentication, considering that I would like to create users in a SqlServer Database, and if it's possible I would like to use Entity Framework for the porpose?

The flow for my authentication would be:
User writes Username and Password, if they are right he receive the JWT Token, without redirecting him/her to the authorization page.

At this point the problem are:
which is the right endpoint to do this flow:
is it the /authorize or the /token endpoint?
I have a lot of confusion for the questions above.

The second thing, what is the best way to retrieve the user informations?
For example if my endpoint needs to understand from the logged in user what are his data, I think that or I retrieve from the endpoint or from the JWT token.

Even here I have no clue on which is the best.

Answer (score 1):

> I read that OAuth is created for Authorization and not for Authentication. For Authentication, seems that exists something else called OpenIDConnect, so the first question that comes to my mind, and on which I cannot find an easy answer is: are OAuth, OpenIDConnect and IdentityServer related technology?

That's right. OAuth was the first one introduced and allows the person requesting it access to the resources (its handing out access tokens). OIDC (OpenID Connect) on the other-side extends this concept by an identity, the authentication part.

The identity token verifies the identity of the person to your application. Instead of providing identity via username + password (i.e. user creating an account on your website), they get redirected to your authentication provider/app and enter their login there and you get an identity token in return (and/or an access token, depending on the flow and scopes you request).

The identity token is an JWT token (or reference token). The JWT token contains all of the users identity information required for your application (user id, email, displayname, age, etc.) and is cryptographically signed. Only the Identity Server knows the key used to sign it up and you can verify it with the public key from the OIDC (IdSrv here) provider.

Reference token works similar, but claims are requested on the server side and cached.

With identity token you can not access the users resources. Example: Facebook.

When you sign in your application with an facebook account, most page will only request identity token to verify that its the same user (instead of using a username / password combination). But with that one, the application can't access your facebook posts or do posts in your name.

If the application requests an access token (`token` scope), then also an access token will be returned (if the application is allowed to via allowed scopes). You will be asked to grant the permissions to the resources which the application requests.
With that token, the application can read your posts or post in your name.

> Which is the best solution for authentication, considering that I would like to create users in a SqlServer Database, and if it's possible I would like to use Entity Framework for the porpose?

Doesn't really matter. Either one can be used, all you really need is the "sid" (subject id) claim and associate that one with your user.

Identity Server can issue both, depending on what the client asks (if client asks for `id_token` response type, it will receive an identity token, if it asks for `token` an access token. Both can be specified or just one).

> At this point the problem are: which is the right endpoint to do this flow: is it the /authorize or the /token endpoint? I have a lot of confusion for the questions above.

- `/authorize` is used to authorize the user (have him login, and send back to your website). Its used for so called interactive flows, where the user enters credentials
- `/token` endpoint you can only retrieve a token (resource owner flow (username + password), client credentials (for machine to machine authentication), refresh token (to get a new access token by using an refresh token (if you asked for `offline_access` scope, which gives and refresh token)

> The second thing, what is the best way to retrieve the user informations?
>   the `/userinfo` endpoint, see docs: http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/endpoints/userinfo.html

As the doc says to access that, the client needs to request the `openid` scope.

> For example if my endpoint needs to understand from the logged in user what are his data, I think that or I retrieve from the endpoint or from the JWT token.

Yes you can retrieve it from JWT token, if you use JWT token. If you use reference token, its just an ID.

And last but not least the `/introspection` endpoint can be used to validate the token (if your consuming application has no libraries to decrypt and validate signature of the token.

If you can, its best to use the Identity Server client libraries (i.e. `IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation` package for ASP.NET Core or oidc-client for npm/javascript based applications) which should be picking up the correct endpoints, so you don't have to worry about it